# SSH using private key authentication, is asking for password

Tags: ssh

I use AndFTP on my Android phone. I added a private SSH key, to AndFTP. When I enable passwordless authentication in the Linux machine, AndFTP shows an authentication error message.

But using JucieSSH on Android I *can* login without a password.

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: please provide more details, including the application configuration of connection.

Comment: also, have a look at AndFTP documentation, might be useful https://help.hostedftp.com/knowledgebase/andftp-tutorials-connecting-uploading-downloading/

Comment: Does your private key require a passphrase? Did you configure JuiceSSH to save the passphrase, but not AndFTP? Also, please clarify what you mean by "passwordless authentication in the Linux machine". Allowing empty passwords and denying password authentication are two entirely separate configuration items, please be precise and clear with your description otherwise we don't know what you mean.

Comment: What is the precise text of the "authentication error message"?

Comment: passwordless authentication in the Linux machine only connect the ssh server using privet ar a public key